# PHP Foreach loop returns result twice

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a fill-in-the-blank text with php where the parts to be filled are stored in my SQL database with curly brakets.

Fore example:

> 7 5 10 7 21 17 68 {63} {315}

{63} and {315} should be replaced by inputs type text with `size="2"` for the first and `size="3"`for the second one.

I created a regex (thanks to SO) and the `preg_match_all` function returns an Array with the identified values.

```
$chapitre_name = "7 5 10 7 21 17 68 {63} {315}";
$regex = '~\{([^}]*)\}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $chapitre_name, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Returns the array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '63' (length=2)
  1 => string '315' (length=3)
```

Then to replace those values I created a `foreach` loop to calculate the length and create an input for each value.

```
$input = '';
foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value_resultat ) {
    $length = strlen($value_resultat);
    $input .= '<input type="text" name="'.$chapitre_id.'[]" value="'.$value_resultat.'" size="'.$length.'" />';
}
$chapitre_name = preg_replace($regex,$input,$chapitre_name);
```

(Obviously the `value ="'.$value_resultat.'"` is only for debugging purpose.)

My problem is when I `echo '<p>'.$chapitre_name.'</p>';`, each field is repeated twice. Eg.

```
<p>7 5 10 7 21 17 68 <input type="text" name="646" value="63" size="2"><input type="text" name="646" value="315" size="3"> <input type="text" name="646" value="63" size="2"><input type="text" name="646" value="315" size="3"></p>
```

As a precision, the fill in the blank text could contain any type of text or digit, on any length and there can be as much blank fields as needed per the Administrator who creates the quizz.

Comment: Your `preg_match_all` returns 2 matches, correct? So, since the `$regex` is the same, your `preg_replace` will also return 2 matches, so it replaces **each** match with **both** fields.

Comment: `$input .=` appends to the string. what happens if you just try `$input =`

Comment: You have `name="'.$chapitre_id.'"` inside the foreach, but I don't see you changing that variable between the iterations in your loop, so all inputs added in that loop will get the same name. In your output, you actually have four different inputs all with the same name (which is invalid). If you want them all to share the same name, you must add `[]` after, like this: `name="646[]"` to make sure you get all inputs in an array when you submit the form.

Comment: @opensource-developer, the `$input = returns` returns the same input twice.

Comment: @GigiSan, do you think I should create two different loops to achieve my goal?

Comment: @gael no the loop is fine, but since you loop over the matches (= for each match), you should only replace the current match with the corresponding `<input>` inside the loop, instead of replacing them all at the end. Also, it might help to capture the brackets too in the `preg_match_all`, so you can replace the entire match easily (e.g. replace `{63}` with the input, not just `63`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` as approach:

```
$chapitre_name =  preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($matches) use($chapitre_id) {
        return '<input type="text" name="'.$chapitre_id.'" value="'.$matches[1].'" size="'.strlen($matches[0]).'" />';
    },
    $chapitre_name
);

echo $chapitre_name;
```

[Test preg_replace_callback](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/null/php/php81/25ac8357aaf40aa50e58344ec5409259/)

or using short syntax with [arrow function and sprintf](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/null/php/php81/125dd278c9dd9b94b8f41cfa6ec84c0c/):

```
$chapitre_name =  preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    fn($matches) => sprintf(
        '<input type="text" name="%s" value="%s" size="%d" />',
        $chapitre_id,
        $matches[1],
        strlen($matches[0])
    ),
    $chapitre_name
);
```